# Подмножества в golang

Tags: golang

Всем привет.
Создать множество можно и заполнить можно так

```
func main() {
    m := make(map[int]bool, 0)
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        m[i] = true
    }
    log.Println(m)
}
```

Так ли это и если да, то как создать для множества подмножество

Нужно что-тотипа такого

`множество[подмножество1{член1, член2, член3...}, подмножество2{член1, член2, член3 ...}...etc]`

```
package main

import (
    "math"
    "sync"
)

type Set struct {
sync.Mutex
mp map[*SubSet]bool
}

type SubSet struct {
    sync.Mutex
    mp map[float64]bool
}

func NewSet() *Set {
    return &Set{
        mp: map[*SubSet]bool{},
    }
}

func NewSubSet() *SubSet {
    return &SubSet{
        mp: map[float64]bool{},
    }
}

func (s *SubSet) InsertInSubset(key float64) *SubSet {
    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()
    s.mp[key] = true
    return s
}

func (s *Set) InsertInSet(key *SubSet, value bool) *Set {
    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()
    s.mp[key] = true
    return s
}

func CelcionSet(celcions []float64) {
    celcions = QS(celcions)
    lencelcions := len(celcions)
    set := NewSet()
    for i := 0; i < lencelcions; i++ {
        rng := math.Trunc(celcions[i]/10) * 10
        sub := NewSubSet()
        set.InsertInSet(sub.InsertInSubset(celcions[i]), true)//это конечно же не сработает, но не понимаю как заставить работать чтобы в множество вставлялось подмножество
    }
}

func QS(nums []float64) []float64 {
    // find len of arr
    lennums := len(nums)
    // if arr contains less then 2 items, nothing to sort
    if lennums < 2 {
        return nums
    }
    toehold := nums[0] //or nums[lennums/2]
    // items which less than toehold
    left := make([]float64, 0)
    // items which more than toehold
    right := make([]float64, 0)
    for _, num := range nums[1:] {
        // move to right if item more than toehold
        if num > toehold {
            right = append(right, num)
        } else {
            // move to left if item less than toehold
            left = append(left, num)
        }
    }
    // recoursive sorting left side
    nums = append(QS(left), toehold)
    // recoursive sorting right side
    nums = append(nums, QS(right)...)
    return nums
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    s := NewSet()
    s.Insert(-18.1)
    s.Insert(-11.2)
    s.Insert(23.6)
    s.Insert(22.5)
    s.Insert(28.3)
    s.Insert(28.3)

    fmt.Println(s.GetAll())
    fmt.Println(s.GetSubsetFor(-10))

}

type measurement int64
type subsetId int

type Set struct {
    subsets  map[subsetId]*Subset
}

type Subset struct {
    elements map[measurement]int
}

func NewSet() *Set {
    return &Set{
        subsets:  map[subsetId]*Subset{},
    }
}

const roundFactor = 10

func toStorage(val float64) (subsetId, measurement) {
    m := measurement(math.Round(val* roundFactor))
    id := subsetId((int(val) / 10 ) * 10)
    return id, m
}

func fromStorage(m measurement, count int) []float64 {
    val := float64(m) / float64(roundFactor)
    var vals []float64
    for i:=0; i < count; i++ {
        vals = append(vals, val)
    }
    return vals
}

func (s *Set) Insert(val float64) {
    id, m := toStorage(val)
    if ss, found := s.subsets[id]; !found {
        s.subsets[id] = &Subset{
            elements: map[measurement]int{m: 1},
        }
    } else {
        ss.elements[m]++
    }
}

func (s *Set) DeleteOne(val float64) {
    id, m := toStorage(val)
    if ss, found := s.subsets[id]; found {
        ss.elements[m]--
    }
}

func (s *Set) DeleteAll(val float64) {
    id, m := toStorage(val)
    if ss, found := s.subsets[id]; found {
        delete(ss.elements, m)
    }
}

func (s *Set) Contains(val float64) bool {
    id, m := toStorage(val)
    if ss, found := s.subsets[id]; found {
        if c, found := ss.elements[m]; found && c > 0 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func (s *Set) GetSubsetFor(val float64) []float64 {
    id, _ := toStorage(val)
    if ss, found := s.subsets[id]; found {
        var vals []float64
        for m, count := range ss.elements {
            vals = append(vals, fromStorage(m,count)...)
        }
        return vals
    }
    return nil
}

func (s *Set) GetAll() []float64 {
    var vals []float64
    for _,ss := range s.subsets {
        for m, count := range ss.elements {
            vals = append(vals, fromStorage(m,count)...)
        }
    }
    return vals
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но наверно стоило упомянуть в задании, что именование подмножеств динамическое. То есть я в цикле должен создавать новые подмоножества по мере поступления новых данных. ТАм задача на диапазоны температурных колебаний с шагов 10 градусов 
`-10{-18.1, -11.2 }, 20{23.6, 22.5, 28.3}` и тд.

Comment: Ну тогда всё сильно проще будет. А в чём затык у тебя?

Comment: Вернул мой код в вопрос. Проблема в том, что я стопорюсь и не понимаю, как использовать то что написал(вот такой вот я ученик. Написать заполнение мап могу а логику как и икогда их заполнять не могу додумать))))) Как создавать разные подмножетва в цикле в функции CelcionSet(). Вообще даже не знаю, пригодно ли это для решения задачи. Дальше в голове перекати поле...

Comment: @Quester обновил

Comment: а можете подсказать, как вот так же с легкостью алгоритмы щелкать? Мне никак они не даются

Comment: А зачем ветвлние в функции Insert(). Итак ведь не запишутся повторяющиеся значения. Только нужно не `map[int64]int` а `map[int64]bool` и тогда эта проверка ведь вообще не понадобится?

Comment: [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1412307/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9) сделал, но все-равно возникли проблемы с запонением и получением значений

Comment: Нашел ошбику все же

Comment: Ветвление в `insert` чтобы создавать новое подмножество, если оно ещё не было создано. `map[measurement]int` нужно чтобы не терять повторяющиеся. Например, в моём коде `28.3` вставляется два раза и выводится тоже два раза.