# Мапа заполняется пустотой

Tags: golang

Все привет.

Необходимо объеденить температурные диапазоны с шагом в 10 градусов. На входе последовательность температур (21,1, 35.6, -10.4, 15.7, 28.9 например), на выходе ожидается -10{-10.4, -15.7}, 20{21.1, 28,9}, 30{35.6}

Я сделал следующее

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "sync"
)

type Set struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    subs map[int]*SubSet
}

type SubSet struct {
    set map[float64]bool
}

func NewSet() *Set {
    return &Set{
        subs: map[int]*SubSet{},
    }
}

// возвращает имя подмножества(id подмножества)
func nameSubset(val float64) (name int) {
    name = int(math.Trunc(val/10) * 10)
    return
}

func (s *Set) Insert(val float64) {
    name := nameSubset(val)
    s.Lock()
    s.subs[name] = &SubSet{set: map[float64]bool{}}
    s.Unlock()
}

func (s *Set) Get(SubName int) *SubSet {
    s.RLock()
    defer s.RUnlock()
    val, ok := s.subs[SubName]
    if ok {
        return val
    }
    return nil
}

func celcions(subsequence []float64) {
    set := NewSet()
    for _, item := range subsequence {
        set.Insert(item)
        fmt.Println(set)
        /*
            // Добавляется три значения в диапазон -20
            &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} map[-20:0xc00000e030]}
            &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} map[-20:0xc00000e038]}
            &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} map[-20:0xc00000e040]}

            // Добавляется 3 значения в диапазон 10
            &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} map[-20:0xc00000e040 10:0xc00000e048]}
            &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} map[-20:0xc00000e040 10:0xc00000e050]}
            &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} map[-20:0xc00000e040 10:0xc00000e058]}

            // Добавляется 1 значение в диапазон 20
            &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} map[-20:0xc00000e040 10:0xc00000e058 20:0xc00000e060]}

            // Добавляется одно значение в диапазон 30
            &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} map[-20:0xc0000a4030 10:0xc0000a4048 20:0xc0000a4050 30:0xc0000a4058]}

            // Все количества значений правильные, но самих значений нет.
            // Каждый раз добавлялось правильное количество пустых мап
        */
    }
    fmt.Println(set.Get(10))
    // &{map[]} //выводится пустая мапа вместо заполненной.
}

func main() {
    cels := make([]float64, 0)
    cels = append(cels, -25.4, -27.0, 13.0, 19.0, 15.5, 24.5, -21.0, 32.5)
    celcions(cels)
}
```

Но на выходе, вместо ожидаемого, получаю пустую мапу(в комментах паказал выводы программы)

Что не так сделал?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ошибку. Не итерировал

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "sync"
)

type Set struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    subs map[int]*SubSet
}

type SubSet struct {
    set map[float64]int
}

func NewSet() *Set {
    return &Set{
        subs: map[int]*SubSet{},
    }
}

// возвращает имя подмножества(id подмножества)
func nameSubset(val float64) (name int, value float64) {
    name = int(math.Trunc(val/10) * 10)
    value = val
    return
}

func (s *Set) Insert(val float64) {
    name, v := nameSubset(val)
    item, ok := s.subs[name]
    if !ok {
        s.subs[name] = &SubSet{
            set: map[float64]int{v: 1},
        }
    } else {
        item.set[v]++
    }
}

func (s *Set) Get(SubName int) *SubSet {
    s.RLock()
    defer s.RUnlock()
    val, ok := s.subs[SubName]
    if ok {
        return val
    }
    return nil
}

func celcions(subsequence []float64) {
    set := NewSet()
    for _, item := range subsequence {
        set.Insert(item)
        fmt.Println(set)
    }
    fmt.Println(set.Get(-20))
}
```